# How to add user id to another table with a submit button

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am creating a site that allows users to view desired 'teams' and can then join them with the click of one button.

I have my **users** table which contains: ***user_id, user_name, team_id***

Then, I have my **teams** table which contains: ***team_id, team_name, team_players***

How would I go about having the users to join a group, each user can also only be in 1 team at a time.

Comment: hi @Danned, if you write some code you can share and we can help you to develop it in mysql you can make a group for example select * from table where user_id=yourvariable group by team_name   or user_id  the point is " group by "whiten you want to make group"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each user to be able to join multiple teams, and each team to have multiple users, then you need a "join table."

Table **teams_users** would contain **team_id**, **user_id**. You can make a composite primary key on team_id, user_id (preventing a user from joining the same team twice).

Then you can get a team with:

```
SELECT * FROM users t1 right join teams_users t2 ON t1.team_id = t2.team_id WHERE t2.team_name = 'the rascals'
```

Even if you only want players to join one team at a time, you might still want to use the join table in case you ever change your mind. It would be very easy. To only allow one team per user, put a unique constraint on **user_id** in the join table. If you later decide you want to allow multiple teams, you just remove that constraint.

If a user tries the "join team" action, you simply check for the user_id's existence in the join table.

```
SELECT * FROM teams_users WHERE user_id = $user_id
```

If it does exist, you retrieve its matching **team_id** and tell them, "sorry, you are already in team 'the rascals'. You must leave that team if you want to join another." If they drop their team, you simply do:

```
DELETE from teams_users WHERE user_id = 5
```

If they add a team, you just do:

```
INSERT INTO teams_users ($team_id, $user_id) #// (assuming PHP variables).
```

The INSERT query will only work if they are not already in a team. If they are you would get an error message. You could also look at "INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..." queries. But I would advise against that because you want to warn users before they change teams.

Comment: I just want to have a member only belong to a single group, so if they aren't currently in one, it is able to to be null, then once the user decides to join another team, then they column is updated with the new team_id

Comment: With a join  table, you can easily add and drop users from a team. You can also easily change to allowing multiple teams for a user with very little work. I usually regret not using a join table when I could have. It's more work to fix it later.

Comment: @Dannad if you need any further clarification, feel free to ask. If any of the answers solved your problem, please mark it as correct by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by adding the team_id field to the users table as a foreign key and allow it to be NULL.

Then you would display the team names in an html form with a radio button for each team.

In a PHP file (which should be set to the action of your form) create an if statement based on the values you assigned to each radio button. In each if block, execute a sql UPDATE statement that will add the appropriate group_ID to the right user instance.